# Is it possible to read the object properties from clipboard

Tags: c#, text

I'm new to c# and i was trying to get the read the foreground color of the selected text from clip board. Let me shed some light on the background.
I have a textarea in a windows form. when the user enters some text into it, the first 3 char are black and next 3 are red. Now I use ranorex to pull out or read objects from forms and get their properties. I can read the text content in the text box but i want to check if the 1st three chars are black and the next 3 are red.
E.g: if the text box contains the text "welcom" then "wel" will be black and "com" should be red.

I thought i could save to clipboard and try to read the element colors from there but if i am wrong do correct me.

Just to clarify: I must also mention that i am trying to read the text from text area of [JMTATextPane or JTextPane] and not from a Rich text box.

Comment: Assuming the copied text is coming from an RTF, you'll need to retrieve the text, place it in a RTF control then perform parsing (or create your own RTF parser, btu that's probably overkill).

This is all assuming it's actually copying the formatting as well.

Comment: you can look at the `Clipboard` class, but you may have to save the data on your own when it is copied from the textbox initially. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asume that your TextBox is a RichTextBox, right? So you can save the complete content of the textbox into the clipboard ( something like `Clipboard.SetData(..,..)` ).

If you want to check the colors you simply select the first three letters and check the color.

```
richTextBox.Select(0,3);
Color color = richTextBox.SelectionColor;
// Do your checking stuff here
```

Comment: I must also mention that i am trying to read the text from text area of  [JMTATextPane or JTextPane] and not from a Rich text box.